# How to create an instance of a DBHandler class inside a class that extends Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio, android-sqlite

This is the constructor in MyDBHandler class.

```
public MyDBHandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
```

Now I have another class which extends Fragment, which is why this code below will not work.

```
MyDBHandler dbHandler = new MyDBHandler(this, null, null, 1);
```

So what is the proper way of creating an instance of MyDBHandler?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so it turns out I just need to get the Activity on which the fragment is called.

```
MyDBHandler dbHandler = new MyDBHandler(getActivity(), null, null, 1);
```